# How to write an end to end test in XUnit

Tags: c#, testing, xunit

I am a novice in testing and using XUnit for writing a test for a very large and complex project. I don't want to write unit tests, I just want to write a single test (kind of end to end test).
My project basically takes a file(contains some items, let's say 10), do some processing and push these items in different lists based on their type. Now after this, some operations are done and if they work fine then at the end the items are deleted from those lists.
I just want to write a test to check if the number of items in the initial file and the number of items deleted should be the same(to check if all operations are working fine as deletion is the last step). How to do that with a single test?

Comment: To do that in a single test, just put the codes into one function. Simple.

Comment: `Assert.Equal(Something.Count, SomeOtherThing.Count, "Hamster died")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You can set up your test just like a xunit unit test:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Given_When_Then() // describe your test
{
  // Arrange - set up the conditions for your test, perhaps set the contents of the file
  var expectedResults = ...;
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\myTestFile.txt", "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4\nline 5\nline 6\nline 7\nline 8\nline 9\nline 10");
  var classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();

  // Act - perform your action that will impact the data
  var results = classUnderTest.DoProcessing();

  // Assert - prove that your data is in the correct state
  Assert.Equal(results, expectedResults);
  Assert.Equal(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\myTestFile.txt"), expectedResults);  // or perhaps assert on the files
}
```

I personally recommend checking out Xunit's [Theory](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/) if you want to create a single test that uses a range of values to assert different scenarios work. You can also check out [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) for a bunch of intuitive and easy to read assertions to make your tests more robust.

Happy testing!